# Не работает написанный код в Visual Studio Code

Tags: c#, build

Выходит ошибка отладки:

> Не удалось найти задачу preLaunchTask "build".
>   Либо:
>
> Выполнение предварительной задачи build завершено с кодом выхода 1.

Как это убрать?

Если что я только-только начал изучать программирование и выбрал для этого язык C#. И когда я пишу `dotnet restore`, выходит это:

> MSBUILD : error MSB1003: укажите проект или файл решения. Текущий рабочий каталог не содержит проект или файл решения.

Использую конфиг *.Net core launch console*.

Comment: А почему вы не используете обыкновенную Visual Studio?

Comment: Она просто у меня не запускается

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы находитесь не внутри каталога проекта.
Если вы создали новый проект через 

`dotnet new console --name MyProject`

То чтобы собрать билд, вам нужно перейти в каталог с проектом

`cd MyProject`

Comment: Может оставить свои данные skype или вк чтобы я мог с вами связатся и чтобы прям по подробнее обьяснили а то я что нечего не понял

Comment: Этот сайт подразумевает, чтобы информация сохранялась и была доступна остальным, кто столкнется с такой же проблемой, можете задавать вопросы здесь